# reorderable list of reorderable list items? (Editor)

Tags: editor, inspector

Is it possible to create an reorderable list which has items that are an reorderable List itself?

[image: reorderableList]

What would be the pattern do do that? Creating a custom inspector for the upper level and one for the item-class or is everything done in the editor-class of the uppermost entity?